# Does eating cheese help one to fall asleep or have a sound sleep?

Tags: nutrition, sleep

Does eating cheese help one to fall asleep or have a sound sleep?

According to [Dr. Oz it does](http://www.sharecare.com/health/sleep-health/can-cheese-crackers-help-sleep):

> Cheese and 100% whole grain crackers are your best bedtime-snack bet. The whole grains help produce serotonin. Cheese, like other dairy products, contains tryptophan. Together, they make for a winning combination.

According to realbeauty.com [it doesn't](http://www.realbeauty.com/health/wellness/sleep-inducing-foods#slide-4):

> If a nap is in your future, steer clear of Parmesan, Romano, Asiago, and other hard cheeses (basically, all the yummy smelly ones!). The high levels of the amino acid tyramine are known to keep you up.

Pong Cheese seem to [second the claims](http://www.pongcheese.co.uk/the-big-cheese/articles/does-cheese-make-for-sweet-dreams.html) made by RealBeauty.

> Cheese contains naturally high levels of an amino acid called Tryptophan. It is from Tryptophan that our brains manufacture the chemical Serotonin which is vital for our well-being and mental stability. Tryptophan can be bought in natural food stores for the treatment of symptoms of depression, Seasonal Affective Disorder and Pre-Menstrual Tension as well as helping with relaxation, restfulness, and a good night's sleep.

---

**Related Questions**

- [Does the combination of red wine and cheese cause bad dreams?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13643/does-the-combination-of-red-wine-and-cheese-cause-bad-dreams)
- [Does eating just before sleeping cause nightmares?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2111/does-eating-just-before-sleeping-cause-nightmares)

Comment: If this is another claim that turns out to be derived from that [British Cheese Board](http://web.archive.org/web/20060115000115/http://www.cheeseboard.co.uk/news.cfm?page_id=240) pseudoscience, I'll scream.

Comment: In response to a (since deleted) question about the British Cheese Board: I have responded in comments about this before. Small sample. Lack of control. Lack of blinding. Fails to demonstrate good sleep. Fails to demonstrate good dreams. Not peer reviewed. Data not available. No significance estimates. etc. etc. It was a very successful marketing scam, that too many people accepted without critical analysis.

Comment: Pong Cheese seem to more closely second the claims made by Dr Oz, don't they?

Comment: @ayaz: And when you have a migraine, you rest a lot, right? :P